# Apache don't serve some file extensions with fake domain

Tags: ubuntu, apache-2.4, ubuntu-14.04

I'm create new VirtualMachine on AWS using Ubuntu 14.04 image then I install Apache 2.4 with `apt-get install apache` command and setup virtual host using fake server name, fake.example.com (see VirtualHost configuration below), then point `DocumentRoot` to `/home/ubuntu/public_html` and the last thing, I create 2 files, test.txt and test.js, contain some data.

Here, this is my virtual host configuration file:

```
<VirtualHost *:80>
    ServerAdmin webmaster@localhost
    DocumentRoot /home/ubuntu/public_html

    ServerName fake.example.com
    <Directory /home/ubuntu/public_html>
            AllowOverride All
            Require all granted
    </Directory>
</VirtualHost>
```

Then, on your machine, you have to add your VM IP to /etc/hosts that looks like:

```
52.74.61.243    fake.example.com
```

(52.74.61.243 is my VM. You can test with this IP)

Try to access with url http://fake.example.com/test.js and http://fake.example.com/test.txt, you will see that test.js can be able to retrieve content normally but for test.txt you will get empty response. File extension I know that have this problem are .css, .txt.

If I just change server name to the real domain, all other configurations are remain the same, these files are served normally.

Please help me find why this problem occurred.

---------------- UPDATE -----------------------

I checked with both apache and nginx and the problem occurred on both. I tried to retrieve files on local server which is working fine. I think root of this problem may be on somewhere else, not on apache itself. I will keep finding root cause.

---------------- UPDATE 2 ----------------------

I create another vm on different region and execute `wget http://fake.example.com/test.txt` which is working fine. It make me think that my PC is the root cause but it is not, I tested with other PC and facing the same problem. I also test with different internet connection (on same ISP) but I still found the problem. Now, the problem is scoped down into my ISP.

Anyone have been tested on my url?

Comment: What does the log files say? What response code do you get? Have you tried it with an actual minimal HTML file instead of just a text file?

Comment: @Sven No incoming access to access.log nor error.log and for .html is served normally. As I said, this problem happen only some file format, includes .txt and  .css.